# Set an event handler to listen for a named input click event

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Okay, this should be pretty easy.

I have an input on a form that triggers the page to move to the next part of the form(on another page). I need to listen to that element for a click event and run a javascript function when it is clicked.

Problem is, most of the samples online show element types and element ids as the indicator of what to listen to, ie #confirm or input.

What I need is a way to listen to:

```
<input type="image" name="eventName.sbContinueEvent">
```

So far, I have this set to listen to input, but I need to further identify it as input with name of eventName.sbContinueEvent so as to not have it trigger on every input. I would apply an id, however this is a SAAS and I am not able to modify the code like that.

```
 $("input").click(confirmedOrder);
```

Am I missing something obvious or is this something that requires more in-depth coding?

Comment: The [jQuery API documentation](http://api.jquery.com) and [learning center](http://learn.jquery.com/) are extremely helpful. In particular, see the third example on the [Selecting Elements](http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/selecting-elements/) tutorial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('[name="eventName.sbContinueEvent"]').on('click', confirmedOrder);
```

note that if the page reloads, it could do so before the javascript function completes.

Comment: That is why I set the function being called to be a synchronous post request, lol.